# Mocha and Sinon issue with JS Unit test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

This is my basic JS to concatenate two strings, the `context.getVariable` is something which I want to mock using Sinon,

```
//util.js
var p;

function concat(p) {
  var first_name = context.getVariable('first_name');
  var res = p.concat(first_name);
  return res;
}

concat(p);
```

I have added this `test.js`,

```
var expect = require('expect.js');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var rewire = require('rewire');

var app = rewire('./util.js');

var fakeContext = {
  getVariable: function(s) {}
}

var contextGetVariableMethod;

beforeEach(function () {
  contextGetVariableMethod = sinon.stub(fakeContext, 'getVariable');
});

afterEach(function() {
  contextGetVariableMethod.restore();
});

describe('feature: concat', function() {
  it('should concat two strings', function() {
    contextGetVariableMethod.withArgs('first_name').returns("SS");
    app.__set__('context', fakeContext);

    var concat = app.__get__('concat');
    expect(concat("988")).to.equal("988SS");
  });
});
```

I am running,

> node_modules.bin> mocha R:\abc\js-unit-test\test.js

```
util.js:7
    var first_name = context.getVariable('first_name');
                             ^

TypeError: context.getVariable is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import actual context here and then use sinon.stub to mock that getVariable method so it it will get that method when your actual code is running.

```
var expect = require('expect.js');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var rewire = require('rewire');
var context = require('context') // give correct path here
var app = rewire('./util.js');

var fakeContext = {
  getVariable: function(s) {}
}

beforeEach(function () {
  contextGetVariableMethod = sinon.stub(context, 'getVariable');
});

afterEach(function() {
  contextGetVariableMethod.restore();
});

describe('feature: concat', function() {
  it('should concat two strings', function() {
    contextGetVariableMethod.withArgs('first_name').returns("SS");
    var concat = app.__get__('concat');
    expect(concat("988")).to.equal("988SS");
  });
});
```